# How to remove cached non-existing Virtualbox machines, using Hyper-V as provider?

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I was using Vagrant under Windows 10 Pro first with Virtualbox provider and created a few boxes. Then because I wanted to test Docker for Win, I had to switch to Hyper V and uninstall Virtualbox. After some time I manually deleted some Virtualbox machines or re-purposed the folders so they don't have Vagrantfile anymore in them.

When I try to run either
`vagrant global-status --prune`
or
`vagrant destroy -f XXXYYYZZZ`
I get this error:
`The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine 'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The reason is shown below:
Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed. Vagrant uses the VBoxManage binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the VBoxManage binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.`
I understand what Vagrant is trying to say: Install virtualbox binary so it can manage the boxes. But actually there are no VMs to begin with so it should be enough to delete it from registry and for that no Virtualbox is necessary.
 Is there a way how to remove cached boxes from registry in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vagrant is keeping the list of machines it manages under the following location (that is for Mac, you would need to find for windows as I am not fully sure about the path)

```
~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index
```

and under this folder, you'll find a `index` file that will list all machines it has in cache. its a JSon file and the provider for the machine is listed so you can remove anything that is not VirtualBox

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought as well, I just hoped there is some more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks - took forever to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar situation when I try to install Docker on my Windows 10 machine with vagrant + virtual box.

I have uninstalled virtual box, but the same error continues every time I try to run "vagrant up"

> The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
>   'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The reason
>   is shown below:
>
> Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly
>   installed. Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with
>   VirtualBox, and requires this to be available on the PATH. If
>   VirtualBox is installed, please find the `VBoxManage` binary and add
>   it to the PATH environmental variable.

So below process saved me from it.

step 1: Add below line in vagrantfile below line "config.vm.box"

```
config.vm.define "hyperv"
```

Step 2: start your vagrant box calling like below from powershell or cmd

```
vagrant up --provider=hyperv
```

It should work. I got the vagrant running after these steps. 
It must be the provider which is saved as virtual box somewhere in cache or registry.`enter code here`

source: https://willmurphyscode.net/2017/01/16/a-very-simple-vagrant-deployment/